# GDAX deposit accounts - what happens to addresses that change?

Tags: transactions, coinbase.com, gdax

I sent a LTC transfer into a GDAX deposit account. I have done this before without any issues.

The transfer appears processing from the exchange I sent it and it still hasn't appeared in the block explorer, however when I check on GDAX, the deposit address changed. I did a test sending a small amount, and after seeing it went through repeated the transfer to the same address with a larger amount.

I cannot stop or modify the transfer out and would like to know what happens to the old GDAX deposit account?

Will the deposit be recognized by GDAX? Has anybody sent litecoin or bitcoin to a deposit account that had changed before sending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address changed **because you used the old one**.

Don't worry, the transfer is valid, and they keep track of the old address. However, for future transfers they want you to use another address. This is beneficial to privacy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What happens if I used the old address for a new transaction?

Comment: Presumably that will work, but that's up to GDAX.

Comment: I hope it does... otherwise my "best practice" of testing with a low amount and then repeating with the big one just got me into big problems. I'll come back to share the result.

Comment: How so? Just send the bigger amount to the new address?

Comment: I had already sent it to the old one, that is the issue...

Comment: Transfer appeared on GDAX account. So relieved!